# I can not start Eclipse anymore

Tags: windows-vista, java, eclipse, uac, jre

Today, I can not start Eclipse anymore. It worked fine yesterday, then I got a few Windows Updates before turning off the computer. And I also updated to the latest Java RE 1.6_u20 yesterday, but Eclipse has worked fine after that.

When I start Eclipse 3.4 today, the UAC ask me for the Administrator password, and then the Eclipse Splash shows up for a short while, after that nothing more happens. And If I try to start Eclipse 3.5, the same thing happens except the UAC.

What can the problem be? How can I solve this?

**Update:** I have now downloaded the newest Eclipse from the hompage. I unzipped and tryed to start, but I get the same symptoms. Isn't it compatible with the newest JRE 1.6_u20?

**Update 2:** I have tried many things now, but I can not run Eclipse without UAC asking for the Administrator password. And Eclipse doesn't find my printer. Something is wrong with my Eclipse setup. I have tried to download Eclipse again, but it doesn't even start. It could be something with my JRE configuration too. Any suggestions?

If I log in as Administrator on my computer start Eclipse, then UAC still pops up and says "An unidentified program wants access to your computer" (translated by me), and I have to agree before Eclipse starts.

**Update 3:** It seem to be a problem with JRE on my computer, see [I can not start a .jar-file by double-clicking, only from command-line in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/146228/i-can-not-start-a-jar-file-by-double-clicking-only-from-command-line-in-windows). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your eclipse.ini file and add/change -vm option and then start eclipse.exe

```
-vm 
D:/work/Java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin/javaw.exe
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

You can find more information about these settings on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but the UAC still starts up. But why do I suddenly need these lines in `eclipse.ini` ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me. It must be some problems with Java, Eclipse or Windows security settings. Since I get trouble with UAC all the time when I try to use Eclipse now.

Comment: Please check this post -> http://www.touchofdeathforums.com/smf/index.php/topic,38148.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Try running eclipsec.exe (rather than eclipse.exe) from a command prompt window. You may see something written to the console before eclipse crashes.

Have you made any changes to eclipse.ini?

Have you tried adding the location of the JRE to your eclipse command line option (the `-vm` argument)?

Comment: Thanks! I made no changes to eclipse.ini. But I tried your suggestion to start `eclipsec -vm "Path to old VM"` and it worked fine again, thanks.

Comment: But I can still not start from `eclipse.exe`, but I can live with that.

Comment: Something seem to be wrong with my Eclipse setup, I still can't start it witout UAC... se my updated question.